# Example such that integral w.r.t. absolute continuous measure yields different result

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, density-function

In my current lecture we have the following proposition:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $\nu, \mu$
> be measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$ with
> $\mu$-density $f$. Then for every measurable **positive** $h: \Omega
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ holds
>
> $$\begin{equation*} \tag{$*$} \int h \,d\nu = \int f h \,d\mu
>  \end{equation*}$$
>
> In particular we have for **every** measurable function $h: \Omega
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$\int |h| \,d\nu < \infty \Longleftrightarrow \int |hf| \,d\mu <
>  \infty$$
>
> In the case of a finite result $(*)$ holds as well.

Now naturally I'm wondering why we need the assumption of non-negativity. But I can't come up with a counterexample. Where can this fail?

Comment: I suppose $\nu, \mu$ are positive measures. If $h$ assumes positive as well as negative values, then the integrals in $(\ast)$ need not make sense. If at least one of $\int h^+\,d\nu$ and $\int h^-\, d\nu$ is finite, then $(\ast)$ holds, but if both are infinite it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, this does makes sense. One could just write _Let $h$ be $\nu$-integrable_, right? Since it can not happen, that exactly one of the integrals in $(*)$ makes sense.

Comment: One could, but noting that the equality also holds if $h \geqslant 0$ with $\int h\,d\nu = +\infty$ is useful too. And the $\geqslant 0$ case implies the integrable case, hence it's more general.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. If you mind posting your comment as a short answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are positive measures, things are different for signed or complex measures.

The positivity (non-negativity) assumption is one of two simple (to state) ways to ensure that both integrals appearing in $(\ast)$ make sense. The other simple way is assuming integrability of $h$ (with respect to $\nu$).

But the non-negativity assumption is much simpler to prove. It is immediate from the definitions (and the fact that a product of measurable functions is measurable) that both sides of $(\ast)$ make sense for a measurable $h \geqslant 0$. And then it is straightforward to show that both sides are equal for such $h$.

Furthermore, it is easy to derive the integrable case from it (decompose the real and imaginary parts of an integrable function into differences of their respective positive and negative parts and use linearity). And by the same method, that $(\ast)$ holds whenever $\int h\,d\nu$ makes sense.

On the other hand, proving the integrable case (that both sides of $(\ast)$ make sense for $\nu$-integrable $h$, and then that they are equal) without first proving the non-negative case seems to be at least difficult. I think it is possible, but I don't see a promising strategy. The natural way passes through the non-negative case.